# Skip the first 3 leading characters using RegEX

Tags: regex

I am looking for a RegEX that would match/select all but the first 3 characters of a string (including whitespace). That is, select from the 4th character onwards, and if there is no 4th (or 3rd, or 2nd) character, there will be no match.

**EX1.** Given String: "ABC COMPANY"

RegEX should match " Company"

**EX2.** Given String: "JASON'S PAINTING"

RegEX should match "ON'S PAINTING"

**EX3.** Given String "AB"

RegEX should not match anything.

I have been able to come up with an expression that would match only the first the characters `^.{3}\s*`, but this is the invert of what I would need.

This is not being used in any programming language so I cannot use string manipulation. For context, this is using Oracle's Enterprise Data Quality RegEX Replace processor.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? Why wouldn't `SUBSTR` be more appropriate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know whether the `Oracle's Enterprise Data Quality RegEX Replace processor` supports the Lookaround or not. But Here is the usual regex if it supports:

```
(?<=^...)(.*)
```

Here using positive lookbehind `(?<=^...)` it is checking that the match is after the three characters from the begin.

[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jT3aH9)

Comment: I am surprised that it did in fact support the look around, but it does. The first regex that you posted worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm a rookie with regex, but try: `(?<=.{3}).+`

The part within the parentheses is a positive lookbehind - it gives up the match and only return whether a match afterwords is possible or not. 
The .+ token means there have to be at least one character. If you know all the characters will be word characters (0-9 a-z A-Z and underscore) or a whitespace, I recommend replacing the later dot with [\w\s].